# Probability of the sample mean of a Bernoulli

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

If $X_{1}, X_{2}, ... ,X_{10}$ denotes an independent and identically distributed sample from a Bernoulli(p = 0.4) population distribution. What is the probability that the sample average $X$ equals exactly $0.3\text{?}$ State your answer to three decimal places.

I have simply calculated

[image]

Is my procedure correct? Am I missing something?

Thanks you so much guys,

Comment: What is the rationale behind the downvote? This is a clear question, showing some research effort.

Comment: You rounded TOO EARLY, resulting in an error in your last digit. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's correct. (You computed the probability that the sum of all 10 was equal to $3$, which is indeed the same as the probability that the sample mean is $3/10$.) If that's homework, you may want to spell this reasoning out, but that's all.

You have made some mistake rounding too early (specifically, the $0.6^7$), however: I personally find [$0.215$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Bonimial%5B10,3%5D*0.4%5E3*0.6%5E7&t=crmtb01).

Comment: Thanks Clement, I have 0,214272. Can I round it to 0,215? thanks you so much for your help. I'm doing some quizzes and I wanted to make sure to be able to get the right result

Comment: Well, if you get that result, you should round it to 0.214. But did you round the result at any previous step? (You ideally should not, since multiplying by the (big) binomial coefficient will amplify the rounding error.)

Answer (score 2):

It is correct except for a conceptual mistake in arithmetic that throws off the bottom line, which should be $0.2149908\ldots,$ rounded to $0.215,$ not to $0.216.$

Note:  **Don't round until the LAST step unless you KNOW what the effect on the bottom line will be.**